# How install FreeBSD port with ansible and module portinstall?

Tags: python, ansible, freebsd

I need build port with something as in shell:

> cd /usr/ports/www/nginx/ && make HTTP_GEOIP=YES BATCH=yes

I can find [any](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/portinstall_module.html) document, how run this with [ansible module portinstall](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/blob/devel/packaging/os/portinstall.py) =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add. Unfortunately, the proposed workaround is not idempotent.

`- name: Build Nginx with geoip.
  command: make HTTP_GEOIP=YES BATCH=yes
  args:
    chdir: /usr/ports/www/nginx/`

This means, that it will be always reported as "changed".

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose to keep local file of customized build options and copy it to the host before portinstall.

```
- name: Copy customized build options
  copy: src="{{role_path}}/files/nginx-build-options"
        dest="/var/db/ports/www_nginx/options"

- name: Install nginx from the port
  portinstall: name=nginx state=present
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this operation is not implemented in the [port_install module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/portinstall_module.html) The module is part of the [ansible-module-extra repository](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/modules_extra.html) which means:

> These modules are currently shipped with Ansible, but might be shipped separately in the future. They are also mostly maintained by the community. Non-core modules are still fully usable, but may receive slightly lower response rates for issues and pull requests.

As BSD is (sadly) not very popular, chances that someone will implement the functionality is not very high.

But it is possible to work around these limitations by using the `command` module like this:

```
- name: Build Nginx with geoip.
  command: make HTTP_GEOIP=YES BATCH=yes
  args:
    chdir: /usr/ports/www/nginx/
```

I would recommend to write another task to check the state / version of the port installed on the system and add a `when` clause to the task otherwise Ansible would rebuild the port on every run.